# How to trigger another Jenkins pipeline that needs a $BRANCH variable?

Tags: jenkins

I have 3 pipelines. Say:

`build-and-release`
`build`
`release`

I'm refactoring my pipelines, so that I can just call the `build` and `release` jobs, from within the `build-and-release`. Something along these lines:

```
// build-and-release JenkinsFile
node('master') {
  build job: "build", propagate: true, wait: true
  build job: "release", propagate: true, wait: true
}

// build JenkinsFile
node('master') {
  stage('Build') {
    // do stuff
  }
}

// release JenkinsFile
node('master') {
  stage('Release') {
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

This seems to work as it is, but the `build` and `release` pipelines always assume the branch is MASTER. When I run the `build-and-release` job, I pick what branch I want to build.

How do I make the other jobs use the same $BRANCH that I pick from `build-and-release`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `build` and `release` jobs as parameterized job and then you can send the Branch name as a prameter, as shown below:-

```
// build-and-release JenkinsFile
node('master') {
  build job: 'build', parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}")], propagate: true, wait: true
  build job: 'release', parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}")], propagate: true, wait: true
}
```

And then you can use the **Branch** variable in Jenkinsfile of build and release.

**Note:-** You can configure any other parameter type in above example String Parameter has been configured, for more information please refer the [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)